# Java Array split() displaying all values but giving arrayindexoutofbound exception error

Tags: java, arrays

I am writing code to take input from a file which has records in a given format and then splitting them to display pincodes which i need to compare later and write the records. To do the comparision i am first taking all the pincode fields in the records and storing them in a array.I am able to display pincodes but there is an exception. My method code is below.

```
String[] getPincodesArray(String filename) {



String[] st=new String[30];

int index=0;

try {

    FileReader fr=new FileReader(filename);

    BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(fr);

    String line=br.readLine();

    while(line!=null) {

        String s[]=line.split(",");



        String s1[]=s[1].split(";");

        st[index]=s1[1];

        index++;

        line=br.readLine();




    }


}

catch(Exception e) {


    e.printStackTrace();
}

return st;
```

}

when i am executing this function is main(),I am getting an exception but am able to display all pincodes.The output is

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
at info.pack.Methods.getPincodesArray(Methods.java:270)
at info.pack.studentidpincode.main(studentidpincode.java:18)
```

560054
560076
560098
560054
560097
560087
560054
null
null
null..

I am able to see all pincodes, then why is the exception coming?

Comment: `while(line!=null && index < 30)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your file probably ends with a blank line.  If that's the case, here's what happened:

1. `line=readLine()` reads the blank line; `line` isn't `null` because, blank or not, that last line wasn't the end of the file, so the `while` loop executes an iteration;
2. `String s[]=line.split(",")` gives you either one element or none in `s`, depending on whether `line` contained any spaces or not;
3. Either way, `s` won't have the element at index 1 (and maybe not even an element at index 0!), so `String s1[]=s[1].split(";")` gets the inevitable `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

A minimum solution is to detect and ignore blank lines in the input file:

```
while(line!=null) {
    if (!line.trim().isEmpty()){
        // process the line only if we know it has some data
    }
    line=br.readLine();
}
```

A better solution would go further by checking the result of each `split` to be sure that there is an element available at index 1 before actually trying to use that element:

```
while(line!=null) {
    if (!line.trim().isEmpty()){
        String s[]=line.split(",");
        if (s.length() >= 2) {
            String s1[]=s[1].split(";");
            if (s1.length() >= 2) {
                st[index]=s1[1];
                index++;
            }
            else 
                System.out.println("Missing semicolon");
        }
        else
            System.out.println("Missing comma");
    }
    line=br.readLine();
}
```